# TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1')

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

I'm a beginner of Python user.
When I tried to make a code below an Error occurred

```
import numpy as np
np.array(['a', 'b', 'c']) + np.array(['d' ,'e', 'f'])
```

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1')
```

So I tried to set `dtype = '<U1'`, but It didn't work

```
import numpy as np
np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1') + np.array(['d' ,'e', 'f'], dtype='<U1')
```

How can I concatenate those np.arrays without error?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate array-wise (or) element-wise?

Comment: `+` is concatenate for strings and lists, but numeric addition for arrays.  As the error says it is not defined for character arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to concatenate array-wise :

```py
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = np.array(['d' ,'e', 'f'])
c = np.concatenate([a,b])
print(c)
```

output :

```py
['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f']
```

If you want to concatenate element-wise :

Method - 1:

```py
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = np.array(['d' ,'e', 'f'])
c = np.char.add(a, b)
print(c)
```

Method - 2:

```py
a = np.char.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = np.char.array(['d' ,'e', 'f'])
c = a + b
print(c)
```

output :

```py
['ad' 'be' 'cf']
```

Comment: `np.char.add(a,b)` performs your last string concatenate without first creating the `char.array`.  According to the `np.char` docs this is the preferred method for new code.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj added that